# UILabel Center contents

Tags: iphone, ios, text, uilabel

Here's my code:

```
UILabel *myLabel;
myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 300, 480)];
myLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
myLabel.numberOfLines = 2; // 2 lines ; 0 - dynamical number of lines
myLabel.text = @"Please select at least one image category!";
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size: 24.0];
myLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:myLabel];
[myLabel release];
```

I was wondering if it is possible to center the wrapped text as it is alined to the left side:
[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
myLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

Comment: NSTextAlignmentCenter for ios6

Answer (score 13):

`UITextAlignmentCenter` was the correct method to center the text, but is now depreciated. - [see this  question and answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920321/label-alignment-in-ios-6-uitextalignment-deprecated)

Use `NSTextAlignmentCenter` instead:

```
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

This was mentioned in a comment, just making it clear for rookies like myself.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

`UITextAlignmentCenter` is deprecated from iOS 6!