# How to do text alignment in iOS 6.0 ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6

I am using the below code to get text but i dont know how to do text alignment in iOS 6.0..So,Please someone Help me...

```
        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16.0];
        cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:15.0/255.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:202.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        cell.textLabel.text=[titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

finally after a lot of research i found the answer of my question...

```
label5.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
```

tnx to all who helped me...

Answer (score 5):

This is what you need to do in iOS Devices

> cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

If your are developing something for MAC, you should use:

> cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

Assign Alignment accordingly.

Comment: What is the difference between first and second?

Comment: But question is about IOS 6 and there is No use of `UITextAlignment` instead of it we use `NSTextAlignment` ..... !!

Comment: This really should not be the highest voted answer as it is just wrong as of iOS5

Comment: UITextAlignmentCenter is deprecated as of iOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

```
 cell.textLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;//or whatever you want buddy
```

let me know it is working or not...

Comment: I tried it several time with all its possible alignment but there is no change in the alignment

Comment: If your text label is small, you won't notice any change because the text has nowhere to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Hope this helps.

Please try with another label and add it to the cell:

Write the following code on top of the class:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_6_0
# define ALIGN_CENTER NSTextAlignmentCenter
#else
# define ALIGN_CENTER UITextAlignmentCenter
#endif
```

Then add a label:

```
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30)];
label.text = @"This is a sample text";
label.textAlignment = ALIGN_CENTER;
[cell.contentView addSubview:label];
[label release];
```

Is it works?

Comment: can you please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920321/label-alignment-in-ios-6-uitextalignment-deprecated

please read this thread + what you are getting now ? any error or no changes regarding the code ? + are you getting right output for label color and the font also ?

Comment: are you testing in simulator? Is it iPhone 6.0 simulator ? It should work and the issue is also simple. Please don't be frustrated! I think you can solve your problem, can you please recheck the code and ensure that there is no duplicate alignment code + which alignment are you expecting ? Left, right or center?

Comment: I have edited the answer, can you please check with another label and check that is it working or not. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this man...let see working or not...

write below statement in your common file (for example constant.h)

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

//then to check textalignment for ios 6 or ios 5 write below code .m file where you want to use

if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0"))
{
 cell.textLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;
}
else
{
   cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
}
```

try this ...

Happy Coding!!!!!

Comment: it showing error in this line..if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0"))

Comment: Error is Expected identifier or (

Comment: Yes..i copied it exactly..and paste it in list.h,u have written put it in common file..which is common file ..please let me know i am new to iOS...

Comment: have you imported list.h file in a .m file where you have written that code?

Comment: which simulator you are using iphone 6.0 or iphone 5.0?

Comment: iPhone 6.0...dude can u come on chat...??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21115/discussion-between-niravpatel-and-user1865424)